# Fridge keeps turning off and only back in when I flip the circuit breaker off and back on?

Tags: kitchens, appliances

just wondering if anyone has any ideas, we got home and opened the fridge and the light was off and the fridge was off completely, my husband went downstairs to look at the breaker box and the switches were all in regular place none had flipped, he flipped the kitchen one on and off and it came back on, a few minutes later it turned off again but back on when he did it again?

Comment: "he flipped the kitchen one "   The entire kitchen is on a single breaker?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the breaker is tripped but hasn't completely flipped to the "off" position?  The breakers we have do this and it's hard to notice which one has flipped unless you look very carefully to see if one is ever so slightly dislodged from the "on" position.  If this is the case, switching it to the "off" position is required to be able to reset it to "on".  In my case, when I switch to "off" after it has tripped, the effort required to switch it to "off" feels different than if it was properly "on".

If all that is the case, then you probably want to look to see what appliances or devices on that circuit are new, or if you're operating more than you normally do.  If there's a new device on the circuit, then try relocating it to another circuit or just unplug it to see if the circuit behaves the same.

If there are no new devices on the circuit, then perhaps there's something wrong with the refrigerator, but that is outside my knowledge to troubleshoot.